# angular lighbox problem with dynamic value

Tags: angular, angular-material, lightbox

I am using crystalui lightbox in my project and as i have implement the demo its working fine but when i tried to implement with dynic data its showing problem because as documentation show its syntax for lightbox like this

```
<img src="assets/images/pic1.jpg"  [fullImage]="{path: 'assets/images/pic1.jpg'}" > but when i tried to add dynamic data in the loop its not working because of wrong syntex 

[fullImage]="{path: 'assets/images/gallery/portrait-2/{{item.image}}'}"
```

please tell me how can i use my dynaic image path {{item.image}} with this below is the module site link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@crystalui/angular-lightbox

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Angular bindings like this. I'll give you an example of my usage.

```
<img class="img-fluid" id="user-image" 
        [src]="mediaService.getRenderedImg()" 
         alt="Sample image"
         lightbox
         backgroundColor="black"
         backgroundOpacity="0.9"
         closeButtonText="Close"
         [simpleMode]="true"
         [fullImage]="{path: mediaService.getRenderedImg()}"
    >
```

In your case you should change your code to:

```
 [fullImage]="{path: 'assets/images/gallery/portrait-2/' + item.image'}"
```

Comment: i have tried it but not woerking same approach tried with lightbox somethis like below  <span data-exthumbimage="assets/images/gallery/{{item.image}}" data-src="assets/images/gallery/orignal/{{item.image}}" ></span> but it shows the error  "Can't bind to 'exthumbimage' since it isn't a known property of 'span'." any idea about this